# Magento 1 - Discount for all products except

Tags: magento-1.9, discount

I am trying to add a discount code for 25% off everything except for specific SKUs but it isn't working.

Under the Actions tab, under "Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items" I have set it to apply the rule if ANY of these conditions are TRUE, SKU is not (List of SKUs). However, it is still applying these discount to these SKUs.

Can anyone advise where I am going wrong?

Comment: Hi Scott. It's works correctly on my test site. Check this case if you use configurable product: you should choose all children SKU in the cart rule instead using one SKU of configurable product.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That fixed my issue :)